# How to convert the time now into a custom data format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, time, format

I am using an API, and the API needs this data format:

```
Wed Jan 07 2015 18:58:40
```

How I can convert the time now to this data format, using the `datetime` and `time` modules?

Comment: @Selcuk I need this data format: Wed Jan 07 2015 18:58:40

Comment: @Selcuk 's comment helps you. Look at the answer to the question Selcuk mentioned, specifically the part where the method **`strftime()`** is explained. This is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
print(datetime.now().strftime('%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S'))
```

Would display something like:

```
Thu Mar 24 2016 10:09:18
```

The [formatting options](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime.strftime#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) used are as follows:

- `%a` Weekday as locale’s abbreviated name.
- `%b` Month as locale’s abbreviated name.
- `%d` Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal number.
- `%Y` Year with century as a decimal number.
- `%H` Hour (24-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number.
- `%M` Minute as a zero-padded decimal number.
- `%S` Second as a zero-padded decimal number.

---

To then convert this to a format for sending, you probably want to investigate [`quote_plus()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html?highlight=quote_plus#urllib.parse.quote_plus), for example:

```
from datetime import datetime
import urllib

now = datetime.now().strftime('%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S')
print(urllib.parse.quote_plus(now))
```

This would give you:

```
Thu+Mar+24+2016+10%3A32%3A51
```

Comment: For additional information on formatting options, check [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Comment: 1) Thanks for the answer
2) But If I need "Thu%20Mar%2024%202016%2010:09:18" How I can do it?

Comment: If you are trying to encode it, then more than just the spaces should be escaped. You can make use of the `quote_plus()` function. I have added an example.